# Is there any benefit in using parameters for query parameters that dont change?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, query-builder, dbal

I am writing methods in PHP classes that use QueryBuilder for the DBAL (Doctrine) ORM.

One of the thing I like about this is that we can easily use parameters in the SQL that is generated. However, as I was working on a few queries and I notice that there are many instances where the query has parameters that dont change (like "WHERE is_active = 1") where the "1" has been parameterized.

Is there any benefit to parameterizing these values that are written in these functions that aren't ever truly in line or exposed?

example:

```
$this->db->select('u.LastName, u.FirstName, s.*')
         ->from('scores', 's' )
         ->join( 's', 'user', 'u', 's.user_id = u.id')
         ->where( "s.active = :is_active")
         ->andWhere("s.id = :user_id" )
         ->setParameters(['is_active' => 1, 'user_id' => $user_id]);
```

versus something like this:

```
$this->db->select('u.LastName, u.FirstName, s.*')
         ->from('scores', 's' )
         ->join( 's', 'user', 'u', 's.user_id = u.id')
         ->where( "s.active = 1")
         ->andWhere("s.id = :user_id" )
         ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id);
```

I am not usually a Belt and Suspenders guy, (meaning I do it just to be safe), if there is no benefit, then I probably wouldn't do it.

I have looked at the DBAL docs and MySQL docs and I just don't see anything that tells me one way or the other. Maybe someone else has better Google-Fu or personal experience.

Thanks in advance,

GaryC.

Comment: I personally would go with the 2nd option. Since it is hard-coded, why bother trying to parameterize it. Down the road it might change and you switch to the 1st option, but until then the "what if.." question rarely churns out good code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical benefit. If the value is always a constant `1`, you might as well make it a literal in the query, as you show in your second example.

There may be a benefit that is a developer culture issue, not a technical benefit. If some members of your developer team are novice and have a hard time understanding when to use a parameter and when it's safe not to use a parameter, then giving them a guideline to *always* use a parameter for any value in any SQL expression at least means they will use parameters when they really need to do so.